# Rails 4- Consolidate multiple find_by requests

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called "Post" which has a user defined guid integer field and also a name field which is being used as a blog. What I needed to do was be able to find the post with the url of the post by adding either the guid or name params, but not together, and if the guid gets requested, it redirects to the name param of the post. I have a route called `blog` which I'm using as a path instead of `post`.
(Ex: `http://mysite/blog/53` redirects to `http://mysite/blog/name-given-to-the-post)`

I managed to get it working, but I know it's very inefficient because it's making two near identical find requests, but I know of no other way to do it.

Post_controller.rb

```
def show
     @post = Post.find_by guid: params[:guid]
     @slug = Post.find_by_slug(params[:guid])
     if request.path != blog_path(@slug)
       redirect_to blog_path(@post)
     end
  end
```

I mapped `blog` to `post` in my routes which is why you see `blog_path` for example:

```
get 'blog/:guid', to: 'posts#show', as: 'blog'
  resources :posts, path: 'blog', as: 'blog'
```

Post.rb (Model):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :create_slug

def to_param 
  slug
end

def create_slug
  self.slug = self.name.parameterize
end
.....
end
```

I also had to change `@post` to `@slug` in my show.html.erb file because of the backwards type of logic I unfortunately used.

```
<%= @slug.name %>
<%= sanitize(@slug.summary) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand all the questions in your post, especially the part about the `@post` and `@slug` stuff...

Why are you not assigning both variables to the same object? It should be the same object no matter if it's fetched from the database via the slug or the name, or am i mistaken?

You can query the objects using an `OR` query in your sql like `Post.where('slug = ? OR name = ?', params[:guid], params[:guid])`

Comment: Correct, however the reason I'm not assigning both objects the same is  all because of the `if request.path != blog_path(@slug)` and `redirect_to blog_path(@post)` lines. If they were both @post variables then there would be no way for it to differentiate whether or not it needs to redirect. What mine is currently saying is "if the path being requested isn't being done so by the name, it must be the guid, so redirect to the name." That's why they need to be 2 different variables for 2 different situations

Comment: you can just check if the request-path is the same as the slug. you don't need all that funky magic in there.